# Regex that matches whatever comes after a pattern

Tags: regex, sed

**Important: I have already looked up similar questions on Stackoverflow and elsewhere and I couldnt find a solution.**

I'm trying to make a regular expression that matches whatever comes after this pattern (the pattern itself excluded)

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[-\._a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

[image: Regex]

I tried using `^` as a NOT operator like so:

```
[^([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[-\._a-zA-Z0-9]+)]
```

But it throws a syntax error: `Unmatched '('`. Seems like it associates the first `]` with the first `[` instead of with the second. How to fix this?

I also tried doing a Positive Lookbehind like so:

```
(?<=([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[-\._a-zA-Z0-9]+).*)
```

But it's not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not all programming environments support lookbehinds for regex. It depends on where you want to use it, but you can actually select what comes after your pattern with `[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[-\._a-zA-Z0-9]+(.*)`. You just need to tell the software that you are looking for what is in the parenthesis, that is the first group, not the first match.

Comment: I want to use this in a sed command. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture all that follows the match in group 1, and use group 1 in the replacement.

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[-._a-zA-Z0-9]+(.+)
```

The contents of file to test with:

```
hello/w0rld/blbalba0
hel-lo/wor_ld?q=0
hello/w0rld)/blbalba0
hel-lo/wor_&ld?q=0(
```

As you mention in the comments that you want to use `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[-._a-zA-Z0-9]+(.+)/\1/' file
```

Output:

```
/blbalba0
?q=0
)/blbalba0
&ld?q=0(
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```js
const pattern = new RegExp('([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[-\._a-zA-Z0-9]+)([\/\?].*)');

if(pattern.test('hello/w0rld/blbalba0')){
  console.log('Matches string 1');
}


if(pattern.test('hel-lo/wor_ld?q=0')){
  console.log('Matches string 2');
}

// Invalid string
if(pattern.test('hello/w0rld)/blbalba0')){
  console.log('Matches string 3');
}

// Invalid string
if(pattern.test('hel-lo/wor_&ld?q=0')){
  console.log('Matches string 4');
}

// if you wish to access the matches
const matches = pattern.exec('hel-lo/wor_ld?q=0');
console.log(matches[2]);
```

###### [Playground](https://regex101.com/r/B62nXV/1)

Comment: What is valid and invalid? I want the regex to match not the entire thing but only what comes after the pattern. E.g. in `'hello/w0rld)/blbalba0'` match `')/blbalba0'` and in `'hel-lo/wor_&ld?q=0'` match `'&ld?q=0'`

Comment: Yes, check the example. In the last two lines of code, I'm testing string and getting access to the matches. Also, I've assumed `)` and `&` these are invalid characters as you've not specified them in the question. So just to show you that the example validates strings I've created valid & invalid examples.

Comment: Anything is valid as long as it comes after the pattern. The pattern itself though should be excluded from the match..

Comment: So as per your question, this is the base pattern `[-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[-\._a-zA-Z0-9]+`. As per this `(` and `&` are invalid characters in the string.

Comment: The example tests if the string follows this base pattern first `([-a-zA-Z0-9]+\/[-\._a-zA-Z0-9]+)`. If yes, then captures everything after the matched pattern in the third group i.e `([\/\?].*)`.

Comment: Why in the seventh hell does that third group need to start with `?` or `/`?

Comment: As per the images shown in the question, you had `?` and `/` that needed to be matched. If you wish to match any characters and `?` or `/` is not mandatory for start of string then let me know, I will update my answer.